# What is the minimum jump range inside the bubble to get anywhere?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Some ships have really awful FSD range. Or you need to save on some module for power or money. So I am wondering, what is the minimum jump range needed on a ship to be able to plot a route to anywhere inside the Empire?

Comment: All of Empire space is kind of large. I found myself stranded with a default Vulture somewhere in Empire space though, with a jump range or 8. You can probably get away with 10 for most places in empire space though. Just an anecdote, though. I don't have any real way of determining if it's right for all systems in Empire space.

Comment: No, I mean the pure distance between Systems. With my Vulture I often could not even get into certain system because the max Jump Range from one to the other was around 7 LY on the Vulture.

Comment: Down-voting because there's really no way to authoritatively answer this, let alone answer it in a way that remains accurate over the long-term. The "bubble" is a vast collection of star systems which may never be fully explored nor mapped by the player community. It's also a realm that may be subject to growth in the future, at the whims of the developers. "Inside the Empire" is even more volatile, as system ownership changes between factions on a weekly basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a 100% accurate answer would require quite a bit of data analysis. Pulling some data dumps from EDDB and/or EDSM would have the raw data required...

In my experience, about 10LY is the minimum required in order to be able to reasonably reliably be able to reach systems within the bubble. There may be a few locations you need more than that to get to, but it seems to be quite rare within the bubble. For example, my "home base" system requires a 9.5LY jump range to reach, but that's a fairly rare situation.

Note: outside of the bubble is a different story; exploring various areas outside of the bubble can require much larger jump ranges.

I recommend that you don't upgrade to a new ship until you are able to, at least, fit it with mostly C parts and an A-rated frameshift drive. You should be able to get over 12LY with almost any build of any ship that includes the top FSD it can fit. Note that you can set your power priorities to make the FSD's power-draw a non-issue.

(Side note: the Empire really doesn't have a well-defined border. There's a core Imperial area where most systems are controlled by an Empire faction and/or Power, but there are Empire factions scattered all over the bubble.)